# Trim a line to just a string batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I have over 2000 of these (similar) in a text file:

```
2018-07-07_11_38_MA_output_log.txt:[13:00:54] Accepted authentication token of user 76561198071607345 with global ban status 0 signed by Warsaw 1 server.
2018-07-07_11_38_MA_output_log.txt:[14:07:55] Accepted authentication token of user 76561198071607345 with global ban status 0 signed by Warsaw 1 server.
2018-07-07_11_38_MA_output_log.txt:[14:49:50] Accepted authentication token of user 76561198071607345 with global ban status 0 signed by Warsaw 1 server.
2018-07-07_11_38_MA_output_log.txt:[14:51:56] Accepted authentication token of user 76561198071607345 with global ban status 0 signed by Warsaw 1 server.
2018-07-07_11_38_MA_output_log.txt:[15:35:53] Accepted authentication token of user 76561198139232244 with global ban status 0 signed by Warsaw 1 server.
```

I need to trim these down to just the `76561198071607345` (they are not all identical).

I also grab these all from logs using a batchfile:

```
cd ..
cd servers\1\logs

findstr /R 7656*  *_MA_output_log.txt >> "..\..\..\tools\pre-results.txt"
```

Comment: Please provide more samples of the data.

Comment: I have formatted the data and added several more samples, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy one (because of the beautiful structure of the data):

```
for /f "tokens=7" %a in (t.txt) do @echo %a
```

(this is command line syntax. For use in a batch file, use `%%a` instead of `%a`)

Comment: I was thinking to use `syntax-replace` to remove parts of the strings. Forgot that `"tokens=7"` will simply look for the 7th text in the line. This is why I love this site, great response!

Comment: okay so i got it to print them out into CMD, but it doesnt seem to work when I put it in the batchfile that initially grabs the lines. lemme put the initial code into the post

Comment: @LordofKhaos Just use the `pre-results.txt` as your textfile your saving the results to. Then you can save the edited results to a new text file using `>>`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Read the text file line by line:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("pre-results.txt") do (
    rem // Store current line:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Split off file name part from string:
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    rem // Split off time part:
    set "LINE=!LINE:*] =!"
    rem // Extract string portion of interest, but only if fixed string is found:
    for /F "tokens=6" %%K in ('cmd /V /C "echo(^!LINE^!" ^| findstr /B /C:"Accepted authentication token of user "') do (
        endlocal
        rem // Return desired string portion:
        echo(%%K
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)
```

(This regards that the file name part might also contain `]` and that the time part could also contain a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in case the hour part consists of one digit.)